# Why 'T' is associated with Generic and not 'G' in .Net and Java

Tags: java, .net, generics, extension-methods

I am a .Net guy (even though this applies to java also), but I can't find documentation or any literature which tells us why do we use alphabet `T` to represent Generic Class. If it was `G` we could have understood but why `T`.

Microsoft use them by starting them with `T` like `TSource` or `TResult`

```
public static void FooBar<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> Foo)
{
}
```

Not only in .Net but in java also i have seen that this pattern. But Why?

Comment: Is that an answer or question?

Comment: It is a (highly questionable) answer - posted as a comment.  ;)

Comment: duplicate (although I'm finding that the other question is hard to find)

Comment: @BenVoigt: Guilty as charged. No proof.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

T stands for "Type". Which is about the best name you can use assuming your generic class is meant to handle any type.

G wouldn't make sense because the type parameter is not itself the generic class.

Sometimes other initials get used when the type parameter is meant to refer to something more specific, e.g. Key and Value in:

```
Map<K, V>
```

Comment: T stands for type and also for template (the origins of generics)... :D

Comment: @Alex, true about the origins, but if T stood for Template it would have the same issue as G - the T is the type parameter in the template, not the template itself :-)

Answer (score 4):

According to the Oracle documentation, T stands for "Type".  [Source](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/gentypes.html).